# Leaking memory using web sockets on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, websocket, tomcat8

We are using Tomcat 8.5 on Windows server and experiencing memory leak caused by using web-sockets. The server web-socket looks like this:

```
package ad.ecs.async.websocket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import ad.common.Global;
import ad.ecs.async.AsyncEngine;
import ad.ecs.async.AsyncResponse;
import ad.ecs.async.AsyncType;
import ad.ecs.db.DatabaseEngine;
import ad.ecs.db.paradox.User;
import ad.ecs.security.engine.SecurityEngine;

/**
 * @author Serge Perepel
 * @since Aug 23, 2017 12:23:32 PM
 */
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/asyncMsg", encoders = AsyncResponseEncoder.class)
public class ECSAsync {

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) throws IOException{
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connection Established");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String login(String sessionID, Session session) {
        AsyncEngine.INSTANCE.wsConnect(session, sessionID);
        org.hibernate.Session dbSession = DatabaseEngine.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            int userID = SecurityEngine.INSTANCE.getUserIDBasedOnSessionID(sessionID);
            User user = (User) dbSession.get(User.class, userID);
            if (user != null) {
                if (user.getNextLogin() == 1) {
                    AsyncResponse response = new AsyncResponse();
                    response.setType(AsyncType.None);
                    response.setData(Arrays.asList("PASSWORD"));
                    response.setObjData("PASSWORD");
                    AsyncEngine.INSTANCE.addTransientResult(sessionID, response);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            dbSession.close();
        }
        return "ok"; 
    }

    @OnClose 
    public void close(Session session, CloseReason reason) {
        AsyncEngine.INSTANCE.wsDisconnect(session);
    }

    @OnError
    public void error(Session session, Throwable error) {
        Global.INSTANCE.getLogHelper().exception(error);
        //session.close(new CloseReason(closeCode, reasonPhrase));
    }
}
```

Front end opens connection and sends invalid sessionID which causes
the line `AsyncEngine.INSTANCE.wsConnect(session, sessionID);` to throw exception and after that disconnect happens on the front end. At this point front end opens new connection and process goes into the loop. I'm assuming that the connection handler suppose to get freed after a disconnect happen. But it seems to accumulate.

Here is the report from Memory Analyzer plugin in Eclipse:

```
One instance of "org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler"
loaded by "java.net.URLClassLoader @ 0x720029098" occupies 2,153,196,128
(88.10%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of 
"java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]
java.net.URLClassLoader @ 0x720029098
```

Here is the wsConnect method:

```
public synchronized void wsConnect(Session session, String sessionID) {
    SecurityEngine.INSTANCE.checkSession(sessionID); // Exception is thrown here
    connections.put(sessionID, session);
    if (transientResponses.containsKey(sessionID)) {
        transientResponses.get(sessionID).values().stream()
        .forEach(p -> addTransientResult(sessionID, p));
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `AsyncEngine.INSTANCE.wsConnect` is your code. It would have helped if you could show code for it as well.

Comment: Like I said in this particular case this always throws exception

Comment: Yes but that does not mean the problem is not in `wsConnect`. Since it can open connection, throw exception and never close it.

Comment: `wsConnect` is not doing anything with websockets, its just storing the session into a map if the sessionID match. If sessionID is invalid it throws the exception. We log the exception and we see thousands of them in the logs.

Comment: I added the method